# jhipster microservices running mixed in docker and locally. Gateway cannot access UAA

Tags: docker, microservices, jhipster

I have a question about jhipster working combined with docker and localhost. I have started the registry and the uaa apps using docker compose, everything is fine. Then i started locallly one microservice and the gateway. Both of them are sucessfully seen in the registry instances view. The problem is, that when the gateway tries to connect to the uaa (`uaa/oauth/token`) it fails (`I/O error on POST request for http://uaa/oauth/token`). I have tried to set in /etc/hosts uaa localhost but it did not help. Does anybody have an idea how to deal with this issue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The UAA server will have a port as well as a host name. Both will need to be specified. To specify the port you will need to change your application.properties.